# How to send objects of different class in one Json message so that they can be deserialised using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to send message (using RabbitMQ, but I think it's not important). The message text is in Json. I want to send information about two classes in one message. On the listener site I want to deserialize message using Gson, so that I obtain my objects again.

One object is a simple object and the second is a list of simple objects. I couldn't find how to serialise two different objects into one Json, so I packed them in a map and made a message out of this map:

```
A a = new A();
ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
bList.add(new B());
bList.add(new B());

HashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("A", a);
map.put("B", bList);

String messageText = gson.toJson(map);
```

If I now want to deserialise the message:

```
HashMap<String, Object> sentItems = gson.fromJson(messageText, HashMap.class);
A a = (A) sentItems.get("A");
Collection<B> bList = (Collection<B>) sentItems.get("B");
```

I get an exception from the line with `get("A")`:

```
com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to A.
```

Can I fix this or should I follow some other approach to obtain what I want?

**Edit:**

The error is the same if I inform Gson of type I want to use:

```
   Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
    HashMap<String, Object> sentItems = gson.fromJson(argument.getValue(), type);
```

Comment: How would GSon know you want an instance of `A` as a map value? Create a *class* which has `a` and `b` as instance variables of the appropriate type.

Comment: One option would be to send a JSON array with the objects into the array, read the JSON array then deserialize individual array elements; I'd know how to do it with Jackson but not Gson... You need to know how to deserialize from a `JsonElement`.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik You were right, but adding the type (see edit) didn't help. I get the same error.

Comment: I don't see in your edit how you involved a custom class with typed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to first to deserialize the "messageText" to JsonObject like this:

```
JsonElement jsonElem = gson.fromJson(messageText, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElem.getAsJsonObject();
```

and then extract elements by their names, and deserialize to requested type:

```
JsonElement jsonA = jsonObject.get("A");
A a = gson.fromJson(jsonA, A.class);
```

And for the list element:

```
JsonElement jsonBs = jsonObject.get("B");
Type bListType = new TypeToken<List<B>>(){}.getType();
List<B> dataSetIds = gson.fromJson(jsonBs, bListType);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create one class which include two variable one of class `A` and other is `List of class`B` value, and deserialize that new class.

```
Class Parent{
    private A a;
    private ArrayList<B> bList;  

   //getter and setter method here.
}
```

At time of Deserialize, deserialize your JSON string into class `Parent` object, get value of `a` and `bList` from getter method as shown below :

```
Parent p = gson.fromJson(messageText, Parent.class);  
A a = p.getA();  
ArrayList<B> bList = p.getBList();
```

**EDIT :**
Name of the variable inside class `Parent` that is `a` and `bList` is the same as key of your HashMap `map` in other side. In your case it should be `A` instead of `a` and `B` instead of `bList`.

Comment: I think you're right, but I didn't want to make such a class, because it is not semantically justified.